# Displaying Docbook section titles in TextMate's function popup

Tags: textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

I'm working on a bundle for DocBook 5 XML, which frequently includes content like:

```
<section>
  <title>This is my awesome Java Class called <classname>FunBunny</classname></title>
  <para>FunBunny is your friend.</para>
</section>
```

I want the titles for sections to appear in the function popup at the bottom of the window. I have this partially working using the following bundle items.

Language Grammar:

```
{   patterns = (
    {   name = 'meta.tag.xml.docbook5.title';
        match = '<title>(.*?)</title>';
        /* patterns = ( { include = 'text.xml'; } ); */
    },
    {   include = 'text.xml'; },
);
}
```

Settings/Preferences Item with scope selector `meta.tag.xml.docbook5.title`:

```
{   showInSymbolList = 1;
symbolTransformation = 's/^\s*<title\s?.*?>\s*(.*)\s*<\/title>/$1/';
}
```

The net effect of this is that *all* title elements in the document are matched and appear in the function popup, excluding the `<title></title>` tag content based on the `symbolTransformation`.

I would be happy with this much functionality, since other interesting things (like figures) tend to have formal titles, but there is one issue.

The content of the `title` tags is not parsed and recognized according to the rest of the `text.xml` language grammar. The commented-out `patterns` section in the above language grammar does not have the desired effect of fixing this issue -- it puts everything into the `meta.tag.xml.docbook5.title` scope.

Is there a way to get what I want here? That is, the content of the `title` elements, optionally just for `section` titles, in the function popup *and* recognized as normal XML content by the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In TextMate grammars you need to use the begin/end type rules instead of match type rules, if you want to 'match within a match'. (You can actually use a match as well, but then you need to use currently undocumented behavior, available only for TextMate 2)

```
{   patterns = (
    {   name = 'meta.tag.xml.docbook5.title';
        begin = '<title>';
        end = '</title>';
        patterns = ( { include = 'text.xml'; } ); 
    },
    {   include = 'text.xml'; },
);
}
```

This has the added benefit of allowing `<title>...</title>` that span more than one line.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful. It still has a side effect of treating the contents of the title tag differently enough that the text is shown in a different color. (It was white, now it is blue, in my theme.) Any way around this?